# How to get TemplateHelper to deal with UTF-8 BOM, EOL convention, and read/execute permissions?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

### What I'm Trying To Do

I'm trying to use FAKE's `TemplateHelper` to instantiate some template files which become shell scripts (both Unix and DOS).  I was doing that in a FAKE task like this:

```
CopyFile (buildApp @@ product + ".sh") (srcTem @@ "mono-launcher.sh")
processTemplates substs [(buildApp @@ product + ".sh")]
```

where `substs` was the var->value mappings to substitute, and `srcTem` and `buildApp` are the template source directories and the build output directories, respectively.

### What Went Wrong

I encountered 3 issues:

First, `TemplateHelper.processTemplates` was writing a UTF-8 BOM at the front of the generated script.  On Unix at least, this messes up the shebang line and gives an error message when the script is run.  An octal dump of the 1st line of the original template and the generated file show the appearance of these 3 troublesome bytes:

```
$ head -1 ./src/templates/mono-launcher.sh | od -c
0000000    #   !   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \n
$ head -1 ./build/app/Hello-Fsharp.sh | od -c
0000000  357 273 277   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \n
```

Second, there was no way to say the Unix sh scripts generated should have Unix EOLs in them, whereas the Windows .bat scripts should have DOS EOLs.

Third, there was no apparent way to say that the resulting files should have world read and execute permissions.

This question is about whether anyone knows how to deal with those issues, at least in a way better than what I came up with below.

I did a bit of spelunking in the `TemplateHelper` sources and the environs.  I discovered `processTemplate` calls `WriteFile` which calls `WriteToFile` which uses the value `encoding` defined in `EnvironmentHelper` as `System.Text.Encoding.Default`, which on my system is UTF-8.  That's well enough, but there's no apparent way to pass in a custom encoding, e.g., `ASCIIEncoding`.

### What I Did About It

So... absent any way to persuade `TemplateHelper` to do what I want, I replaced it with the following:

```
/// <summary>Copy a template file from source to destination, making string substitutions
/// along the way and allowing for different file encodings at each end.</summary>
///
/// <remarks>This only exists because TemplateHelper put UTF-8 BOM at the front, breaking
/// script shebang lines.  The EOL choice here works from Unix but needs testing on
/// Windows (will it double up on returns if the build machine is Window?), and the
/// read/execute permission setting is iffy. </remarks>
///
/// <param name="substs">IDictionary of key, value string replacements to make</param>
/// <param name="fromEncoding">Encoding of fromTemplate</param>
/// <param name="fromTemplate">file with the source template</param>
/// <param name="toEncoding">Encoding of toFile</param>
/// <param name="toFile">file to which the instantiated template gets written</param>
/// <param name="readExecute">whether to mark toFile as readable &amp; executable by all</param>
///
/// <returns>Nothing of interest.</returns>
let processTemplate substs fromEncoding fromTemplate toEncoding toFile unixEOL readExecute =

  let ReadTemplate encoding fileName =                 // Read lines of template file, but lazily:
    File.ReadLines(fileName, encoding)                 //  start processing before entirety is read

  let SubstituteVariables substs =                     // Substitute variables in seq of line strs
    Seq.map (fun (line : string) ->                    // Loop over lines
               substs                                  // Fold in effect of each key, val pair
               |> Seq.fold (fun (sb : StringBuilder) (KeyValue(k : string, v : string)) -> 
                              sb.Replace(k, v))        // Generates new StringBuilder w/each var
                           (new StringBuilder(line))   // Initial accumulator is original line
               |> toText)                              // Convert final StringBuilder back to text

  let MaybeAddReturn =                                 // Add extra return if not Unix EOLs
    Seq.map (fun line -> if unixEOL then line else line + "\r")  // *** Test if works on Windows?

  let WriteTemplate encoding fileName (lines : seq<string>) =
    File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines, encoding)      // Write out altered lines (eol chosen how?)
    fileName                                           // Return filename for next step in pipeline

  let MaybeSetReadExecute fileName =                   // Platform neutral, mark read + exec perms
    if readExecute then                                // Only do this if asked
      if isMono then                                   // We're running on Mono
        Shell.Exec("chmod", "a+rx " + fileName, here) |> ignore // *** Horrible kludge?
      else                                             // Not under Mono: do it the .Net way
        // *** Equiv kludge: Shell.Exec("icacls", fileName + " /grant S-1-1-0:RX", here) |> ignore
        let fs = File.GetAccessControl(fileName)       // Mac OSX: System.NotSupportedException
        fs.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(     // 
                           new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
                           FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                           AccessControlType.Allow))   // *** Seems pretty complex for such a simple
        File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fs)            //  task as just setting rx permissions!

  let shortClassName obj =                             // Just class name, no namespacey qualifiers
    let str = obj.ToString() in str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)
  logfn "  Template %s (%s) generating %s (%s, %s EOLs%s)." 
    fromTemplate (shortClassName fromEncoding)         // Where we're coming from, 
    toFile       (shortClassName toEncoding)           //  where we're going,
    (if unixEOL then "Unix" else "DOS")                //  and in what condition we propose to
    (if readExecute then ", read/execute" else "")     //  arrive there

  fromTemplate                                         // Start with the input template filename
    |> ReadTemplate fromEncoding                       //  read it in lazily (enumeration of lines)
    |> SubstituteVariables substs                      //  substitute variables in each line
    |> MaybeAddReturn                                  //  fiddle with EOLs for target platform
    |> WriteTemplate toEncoding toFile                 //  write out in destination encoding
    |> MaybeSetReadExecute                             //  finally set permissions if asked
```

It processes the files one at a time, instead of in a sequence like `TemplateHelper` because it's too hairy to supply parallel sequences of read & write encodings.  But as a bonus, it eliminates the use of mutable state I found in the sources, making it more functional, if anybody cares.  The added features are the ability to supply input and output encodings, handle EOLs, and optionally set read/execute permissions on the generated file.

Here's an example of it in use:

```
Target "BuildLauncherScripts" (fun _ ->                // Scripts really only needed for mono
  let asciiEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding()              // Avoid UTF-8 BOM which breaks shebang lines
  let generateAScript (fromTempl : String) =           // Instantiate a script from template file
    let ext = fromTempl.Substring(fromTempl.LastIndexOf('.'))
    processTemplate projProps                          //   projProps to substitute template vars
      asciiEncoding (srcTem   @@ fromTempl)            //   copy from templates to build area
      asciiEncoding (buildApp @@ (projProps.Item("@product")) + ext)
      (ext = ".sh") true                               //   always executable, because it's a script
  generateAScript "mono-launcher.sh"                   // Unix script to launch mono + application
  generateAScript "bat-launcher.bat"                   // Windows script to just launch application
)                                                      //
```

### What I'd Like To Hear From You

1. Is there a way to get `TemplateHelper` to deal with input/output file encodings, EOL conventions, and setting the read/execute permissions?
2. If not, is the above a reasonable way of proceeding?
3. In particular, is the EOL code likely to work on Windows or will it double up on returns?
4. Also, is there some way to set read/execute permissions in a platform-neutral way?  (My code above in `MaybeSetReadExecute` is a frighteningly kludgey mix of shelling out and imitating some .NET code I found but barely understand.)

Comment: This is now submitted as [FAKE/TemplateHelper issue #614](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/614).